# \' (backslash, single quote) in a Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string, backslash, quoting

I am using Ruby 1.8.7, trying to generate a string with the \' characteres, in order to create a script for running in MySQL. The result should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joana d\'Arc', '')
```

But i can't get just one backslash in a ruby string. Using the following code:

```
string = "INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joana d\\'Arc', '')"
```

I got the following string:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joana d\\'Arc', '')
```

And with:

```
string = "INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joana d\'Arc', '')"
```

I got this string:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joana d'Arc', '')
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single%5Fquotes

Comment: If you're trying to manually escape text before plugging it into SQL, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: The two lines `string = "INSERT INTO ..."` look identical to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry Mike, i misspelled it. Now is corrected!

Comment: The documentation uses "puts", which produces the correct result, but saving it into a string, like my situation, doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for the help Till.

Comment: Don't get confused by the difference between what's *is* a string, and how that string is displayed as a result in the console - which will have its quotes escaped

Comment: Also, don't build SQL strings manually unless you enjoy the pain of recovering and fixing broken databases

Comment: @klidebharrow when you mention "saving into a string" are you using irb to look at the value of your string? (edit: Am asking this because of the difference referred to above by @Gareth.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason puts works is that it shows what is actually in the string. The bare console is showing the string escaped. Try this on the console:

```
"Joana d\\'Arc".size
```

You will get back 12. If both backslashes were there you should get 13.

Hauleth's answer should work.

Comment: Yes, should work, and in fact do, but only in console test. When the query runs in the database, the both characters, \ and ' doesn't show up.

Comment: You might try "Joana d\\\\'Arc"

Comment: Worked with the four backslashes. Thanks seph, youre my hero!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, let me add my voice to those encouraging you to try an ORM. It might have helped in this case, but they have many other benefits too.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend avoiding writing raw SQL, and, in this age, I'd use an ORM, even for simple DB use. I highly recommend using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) gem. Borrowing from an [example](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) in the Sequel docs:

```
sequel sqlite://temp
Your database is stored in DB...
```

Using SQLite, that started the sequel ORM in interactive mode, and created the SQLite database called "temp".

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'logger'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > DB.loggers << Logger.new(STDOUT)
 => [#<Logger:0x0000010160bc40 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x0000010160bc18 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x0000010160bbc8 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x0000010160bba0 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x0000010160bb50>>>>]
```

That enabled logging so we can see what Sequel will do as it talks to the database.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > items = DB[:items] # Create a dataset
 => #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `items`"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > DB.tables
I, [2011-11-25T10:17:13.056311 #10130]  INFO -- : (0.000501s) SELECT * FROM `sqlite_master` WHERE (type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence')
 => []
```

Doh! I forgot to create the table...

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > DB.create_table :items do
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 >       primary_key :id
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007?>     String :name
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008?>     Float :price
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009?>   end
I, [2011-11-25T10:17:20.985851 #10130]  INFO -- : (0.002372s) CREATE TABLE `items` (`id` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` varchar(255), `price` double precision)
 => nil
```

The table is created.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > items = DB[:items] # Create a dataset
 => #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `items`">
```

That created a dataset, which is just a convenient way to talk to a table.

And, that's the payoff:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > items.insert(:name => "Joan d'Arc")
I, [2011-11-25T10:17:45.186945 #10130]  INFO -- : (0.001981s) INSERT INTO `items` (`name`) VALUES ('Joan d''Arc')
 => 1
```

The ORM automatically escapes the characters for you. Your job is simplified greatly.

ORMs are DBM aware, so they know when to escape for a particular database. Your code doesn't change. It's trivial to switch from SQLite to MySQL, Postgres, or even non-SQL databases.

Comment: Does Sequel work on a legacy database? I can only run the insert queries on the database.

Comment: Of course. It's great with them. I use Sequel at work to talk to legacy MySQL and MSSQL DBs all the time. You can use it in the "dataset" mode, which is in my example, or you can have it work in full object mode using models for your tables, allowing full relational interlinking of the tables in your lookups and inserts. It's very smart and generates terse SQL and doesn't bog down the server with dumb queries. It's one of the best gems out there. Plus Jeremy Evans, who supports it, is a member here. You'll get responses to questions from him occasionally.

Comment: IMO, the important example from the readme would, in case of this question, be: `DB['select * from items where name = ?', name].each...`. I.e. it's really easy to introduce Sequel (or, to be frank, any decent ORM) to your existing code, and there's really no excuse not to do it __right now__! :)

Comment: Yes, and being able to quickly incorporate raw SQL is useful. The downside to doing that is it promotes the continued use of raw SQL, which can tie the code to a particular DBM if DBM-specific features are used. Programmatically defining the SQL using the methods provided removes that coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Write it using `%q{}` notation

```
string = %q[INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joanna d\\'Arc', '')]
```

Comment: Works well on console, but it runs on the database the \' doesnt show up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
string="INSERT INTO table (name, description) values ('Joana d"+"\\"+"'Arc','')"
```

I don't know if you must use 1.8.6, but if you can, update to 1.9.2. Its much faster and stabler, along with many more features.

Comment: Tried it on the console and on application. In the console it results Joana d\\'Arc, with two backslashes and the apostrophe. But when it comes to the database, the name is inserted as Joana dArc, without the apostrophe. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the ASCII code is for backslash, but you could try appending that to the first string and then appending the rest. Though everything you've tried leaves me thinking that your interpreter is broken. A double backslash should _always_ result in a backslash.